# Vuetify - Moving item in list all the way down

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Quick Vuetify question for you all! I need to move the social media icons to the bottom of this navigation-drawer.

Having a little bit of difficulty doing so. Can anyone please provide me with some pointers? Code is posted below. Please also note, I want a Vuetify answer as in using Vuetify classes/props to make this work (preferrably no CSS).

NOTE: The below code is wrapped inside of a `v-navigation-drawer>` tag (if that makes a difference).

Thank you!

EDIT: Code isn't formatting property for some reason.

[image]

```
<template>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-item two-line>
      <v-list-item-content class="pb-5 text-center">
        <v-list-item-title class="orange--text display-2">{{
          username
        }}</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle class="text-h6 font-weight-light white--text">{{
          expertOf
        }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
    <NuxtLink
      v-for="(component, index) in components.filter(
        (component) => component.name != 'Name'
      )"
      :key="index"
      :to="path === '/' ? `#${component.name}` : '/'"
    >
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title
            ><v-btn
              block
              depressed
              class="text-capitalize font-weight-light grey darken-4"
              >{{ component.name }}</v-btn
            ></v-list-item-title
          >
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </NuxtLink>
    <NuxtLink to="/blog">
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title
            ><v-btn
              block
              depressed
              class="text-capitalize font-weight-light grey darken-4"
              >Blog</v-btn
            ></v-list-item-title
          >
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
    </NuxtLink>

    <v-list-item class="mb-2">
      <v-list-item-content>
        <SocialMedia />
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

Comment: CSS `position: fixed|absolute; bottom: 1.5em`

Comment: @xandercoded I want a Vuetify answer. I've done the CSS stuff.

Comment: I wonder if using [flex helpers](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/) specifically `flex-column` class with maybe a `v-spacer` would help

Comment: Saying you want a Vuetify answer, not *"CSS stuff"* is saying you don't want to learn/understand how it works, you just want to know what button to press. Ultimately, Vuetify is a tool to apply CSS both statically and dynamically. And it doesn't cover all cases, just the common ones. One could argue CSS barely covers all cases.

Comment: @tao I have already done it using CSS. I want a Vuetify answer. That is why I posted the question. I'm trying to understand how Vuetify works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting exactly what I needed:

[image]

I didn't use any CSS but did need to add a helper div which allowed me to group stuff.

Code as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-list class="d-flex flex-column justify-space-between fill-height">
    <div>
      <v-list-item two-line>
        <v-list-item-content class="pb-5 text-center">
          <v-list-item-title class="orange--text display-2">{{
            username
          }}</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-subtitle class="text-h6 font-weight-light white--text">{{
            expertOf
          }}</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>
      <NuxtLink
        v-for="(component, index) in components.filter(
          (component) => component.name != 'Name'
        )"
        :key="index"
        :to="{ path: '/', hash: '#' + component.name }"
      >
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title
              ><v-btn
                block
                depressed
                class="text-capitalize font-weight-light grey darken-4"
                >{{ component.name }}</v-btn
              ></v-list-item-title
            >
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </NuxtLink>
      <NuxtLink to="/blog">
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title
              ><v-btn
                block
                depressed
                class="text-capitalize font-weight-light grey darken-4"
                >Blog</v-btn
              ></v-list-item-title
            >
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </NuxtLink>
    </div>
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-content class="mt-auto">
        <SocialMedia />
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list>
</template>
```

Comment: Adding `mt-auto` to the v-list-item containing the links or `mb-auto` to the previous one might also work.